# PL / SQL Trigger to write data to a txt file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this problem that writes a text line each time all copies of a movie are checked out. They want to contain the date, movie ID, and movie stock quantity on the text file. I have used a cursor to obtain data from the table, and the UTL_file.FILE_TYPE to write output to the text file. The trigger compiles however I am not getting any file written.

```
create or replace trigger zeromovies_write
After update on mm_movie    

DECLARE

c_id mm_movie.movie_id%type;
c_qty mm_movie.movie_qty%type;
CURSOR c_movie is 
SELECT movie_id, movie_qty FROM mm_movie;
fh UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
v_date DATE;
total VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN

OPEN c_movie;
LOOP
  FETCH c_movie into c_id, c_qty;
  EXIT WHEN c_movie%notfound;
END LOOP;
if c_qty = 0 THEN
select sysdate into v_date from dual;
total := (c_id || c_qty || v_date);
fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ORA_FILES', 'checkout.txt', 'w');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh, total);
end if;
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fh);
close c_movie;

END;
```

I then update the table using the following code (setting qty to 0) but the write does not happen.

```
UPDATE mm_movie
SET movie_qty = 0
WHERE movie_id = 7;

UPDATE mm_movie 
SET movie_qty = 0
WHERE movie_id = 8;
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Writing to a file from a trigger is a tremendously bad idea.  Assuming this is a homework assignment, use a row-level trigger, don't query the table, just use the `:new` pseudorecord.  As it stands, you iterate through every movie in your loop and `c_qty` is whatever value exists in the last row read from the table.  There is no reason to expect that would be the row that you're updating.  If you wanted a statement-level trigger that wrote a row for every movie with a 0 quantity every time any change was made to any row, you could put the logic inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. This looks like a supremely bad idea.
2. Can you successfully write a file outside of the trigger? (Anonymous PL/SQL or stored procedure)
3. `FOPEN` mode of `'w'` is going to open in write a new file every time, isn't it?
4. Oracle has locks and what not for concurrency. Things might not work out well if writing to a file happens from two invocations of the trigger at the same time.

Your code loops through every row of mm_movie in no particular order. Then you test if the quantity is zero of the last row fetched. (That last fetch being indeterminate.) So there could be rows with zero quantity , but as long as the zero quantity row is not the last one your zero processing logic won't fire.

This trigger loops through all records, not just the changed records. If the last row does have zero quantity, it may have been set to zero *months* ago and already written out to the file many many times.

Did I mention this looks like a supremely bad idea?

Log it to a table. Inserts to tables work well under concurrent load. Use for each row cursor and the :NEW pseudo record.